# How to insert PAST dates into MySQL as Datetime?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

```
if(sqlData.get(i) != null){
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
java.sql.Timestamp myDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(dateFormat.parse(sqlData.get(i)).getTime());
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(i+1, myDate);
```

I'm not sure what i'm doign wrong and i keep geting "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:" on the 3rd line.

These are dates that i have pulled out of a database, and are set in the past.

```
System.out.println(sqlData.get(i));
```

prints out : 2014-04-19 05:48:22

Comment: The problem seems to be with the `sqlData.get(i)` String, which maybe doesn't match the DateFormat you specified. Print the `sqlData.get(i)` value to check.

Comment: The exception is not because the date is past. It is because `sqlData.get(i)` is returning a date that is not in the `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"` format. check each of the values in that list to fid the one with the incorrect format. Also if the dates are from a database, you may be better off pulling them as `Date` or `Timestamp` rather than a `String`.

Comment: @Nivas i am 100% sure that sqlData.get(i) returns a string in the correct format.

Comment: @user3521471 Can you print (sysout) the dates and post the date here that causes the exception?

Comment: I have edited it to print out an example of the date string.

Comment: @user3521471 ...and the format is different :-). You have `/` as the date separator and the date has `-`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date
```

is thrown from `dateFormat.parse(` when the string passed to it is not in the same format as the specified pattern.

Also note that you have not posted the entire exception message (the entire line). It would have been

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:2014-04-19 05:48:22
```

In your case

`2014-04-19 05:48:22` is not in the format `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"`

Your pattern string should be

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss    Note the - instead of /
```

Comment: Wow. I feel so stupid. I spent like 2 hours trying various methods of inserting this correctly. Another pair of eyes is always helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of parsing a date and then creating a timestamp out of it. This was testing and is working, so if you run into any errors, it may have something to do with the data you have and not the code itself.

```
        String dateString = "1999/10/24 10:24:99";
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date dateObj = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
        Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(dateObj.getTime());
```